# How can I add files in repositories

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using git, and I want to import all my files in the respositories I created, I already initialized the git in my local folder, and I don't know what to do next.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you read any documentation or tried anything?

Comment: yup I tried, git add .   but it display like this The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, how do I remove one folder I don't want to add it to my repository ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git add  or git add . For all files
Git commit -am "commit message"
Git push - with your git credentials

There are plenty of explanations about it.

Comment: I tried git add . and it displays "The file will have its original line endings in your working directory." what does it mean?

Comment: It's ok, the difference between LF and CRLF is according to your editor - windows/Unix.

Comment: ok , by the way, is it possible not to include  1 folder ? because it is very big size like the node_modules folder ? but I already push it to my repository

Comment: You can add a gitignore file, and within this file you can add any type of files to be excluded like: .node_modules, further more you can specific the files you would like to commit just don't use the -a (stands for all) in the git commit message

Comment: by the way I use  "git push -u origin master" to push them to repositories?

Comment: git push [remote-name] [branch-name]